# Questions about dual booting Windows 8.1 and Linux – two issues

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, dvd

I have recently installed Debian 8.1 onto my hard disk with an iso image burned to DVD-r. I was trying to install g++ from the terminal when it asked me to insert the DVD from which I installed the OS onto my hard disk before continuing. This, being my first concern, raises my second concern even more. But more detail on the first concern; it didn't work. 
I inserted the CD, and it gave me a very large error message. I tried `apt-get update`, but it gave me the same error. I get this error whenever I try to install anything with `apt-get install` and put in the DVD as it asks. That error is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  binutils g++-4.9 gcc gcc-4.9 libasan1 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5
  libgcc-4.9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libstdc++-4.9-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc g++-multilib g++-4.9-multilib gcc-4.9-doc libstdc++6-4.9-dbg gcc-multilib make
  autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-4.9-multilib gcc-4.9-locales libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan1-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg
  libcilkrts5-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc libstdc++-4.9-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils g++ g++-4.9 gcc gcc-4.9 libasan1 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5
  libgcc-4.9-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libstdc++-4.9-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 0 to remove and 92 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,008 kB/39.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 116 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 [1,008 kB]
Err cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.2.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150906-11:13]/ jessie/main manpages-dev all 3.74-1
  Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
Fetched 1,008 kB in 11s (85.8 kB/s)                                                               
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.2.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150906-11:13]/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.25-5_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 8.2.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20150906-11:13]/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_3.74-1_all.deb  Read error - read (5: Input/output error)

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My second concern, seeing as this whole DVD thing happened, is whether or not I can actually boot into Debian after shutting off my computer without the DVD in. Will that work? Will it automatically boot into Debian if I shut off my computer and turn it back on? I'm afraid to turn off my computer because I struggled to get this working on my laptop in the first place (Lenovo is not GNU/Linux friendly).

Comment: Also, I'm dual booting with Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that APT is configured to look for packages in the Debian DVD set.

edit your sources.list file, make sure that any lines containing ***cdrom*** are either removed or commented.

**Editing sources.list file**

```
# vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
# gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

so your sources.list file will look something like this

```
 deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150908-22:01]/ jessie main

 deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150908-22:01]/ jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib 

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

now comment the culprit lines:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150908-22:01]/ jessie main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150908-22:01]/ jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

...
```

or remove them:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

...
```

Note that I've added 'contrib' and 'non-free' repositories. this is needed, for example, if you want decent graphics acceleration, gcc-doc package installed for all archs, etc. AMD and nVidia propietary drivers are included in non-free repos, and some GCC manpages are considered *non free* by Debian because the GFDL (GNU Free Document License) is incompatible with DFSG (Debian Free Sotware Guidelines).

Now, about your second concern, I think it all will go well if you installed GRUB2 to the MBR of the first drive, however, just to be sure, run this command as root.

```
# update-grub
```

if you see all of your operating systems listed in the output, we're sweet.

Comment: Oh hey, forgot about this question. Got it solved a little bit after asking, been running Debian ever since. I'll refer to this if I ever have a similar problem though, thanks.

Comment: well I'm glad you solved. I kinda figure that out when I finally saw that beautiful string that states that this question were asked **4 months ago**, I _really_ should pay more attention to the site UI, LOL!. and yup, let's leave this Q/A here in case you or anyone else trample into the same problem.